# What is the transformation matrix of the linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$ f:M_{2.2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}, $$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} 
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
2a - 4b \\
-6d \\
8a-16b+2d
\end{pmatrix}\beta =\big
(\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
,\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\big),
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\big),
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\big)$
$\beta'= ( e_{2}, 2e_{1}, -e_{3})$ of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ (
these are the standard unit vectors of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$)

What is the transformation matrix $M_{\beta'}^{\beta}(f)= ?$

Well my thought is that

$f(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array} 
\right)) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-4\\
0\\
-16
\end{array} 
\right) = \square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
8
\end{array} 
\right) +$$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
-4\\
0\\
2
\end{array} 
\right) +$
$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array} 
\right) +$
$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
-6\\
2
\end{array} 
\right)$

$f(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
0\\
0
\end{array} 
\right)) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
4\\
0\\
16
\end{array} 
\right) = \square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
8
\end{array} 
\right) +$$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
-4\\
0\\
2
\end{array} 
\right) +$
$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array} 
\right) +$
$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
-6\\
2
\end{array} 
\right) $

$f(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
-1
\end{array} 
\right)) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
6\\
-2
\end{array} 
\right) = \square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
8
\end{array} 
\right) +$$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
-4\\
0\\
2
\end{array} 
\right) +$
$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array} 
\right) +$
$\square \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
-6\\
2
\end{array} 
\right) $

And from the linear combinations of the $squares$ I can fill the transformation matrix in the columns and in this way I will get the transformation matrix. Is my idea correct? And how does the transformation matrix look like?
Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the sens of $f\left(\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right)$ whereas $f:\mathcal M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R^3$ ?

Comment: I'm just trying to find out what these notations exactly mean and I have no clue if that my way of solution correct is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is not correct, since the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$; so it makes no sense to talk about, say$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right).$$

Note that\begin{align}f\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)&=\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\8\end{bmatrix}\\&=0\times e_2+1\times(2e_1)-8(-e_3).\end{align}Therefore, the entries of the first column of the matrix that you're after are $0$, $1$, and $-8$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $\begin{align}f\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)&=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\&=0\times e_2+-4\times(2e_1) \times0(-e_3).\end{align}$$\begin{align}f\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right)&=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\&=0\times e_2+0\times(2e_1) \times0(-e_3).\end{align}$$\begin{align}f\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right)&=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-6\\2\end{bmatrix}\\&=-6\times e_2+0\times(2e_1) \times-2(-e_3).\end{align}$ so that will be the rest?

Comment: and the transformation matrix:$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -4 & 0 & -6 \\
-8 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Something like that. I noticed that$$\begin{bmatrix}-4\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=0\times e_2+\color{red}{(-2)}\times(2e_1)+0\times(-e_3).$$

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -6\\ 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ -8 & 16 & 0 & -2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ how can I compute kernel and image of $f$?

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.